# How to Set Blob Tier In Azure Storage Data Movement Library for .Net

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-files, azcopy

Is there a way to set the tier of the destination blob when copying from a File Share to a Blob Storage? AzCopy, which uses ***Azure Storage Data Movement Library for .Net*** behind the scenes, has ***--block-blob-tier*** option. So, I thought this could be probably possible to achieve using the library.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Storage Data Movement Library still not support copyd blob with blob tier.
Would you like to open an issue in https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/issues to track the feature request?

Would you please share your scenario like the DMlib copy command?

As a workaround, you might can set the blob tier are they are uploaded with DMlib?

Comment: Thanks. I found another workaround. I posted my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

DMLib (Data Movement Library) does not support setting blob tier yet. Regarding “copying from a File Share to a Blob Storage”, are you using  Service Side Asynchronous Copy documented below?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement#choose-copy-method
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.datamovement.copymethod?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously in the answers, DMLib does not support setting the blob tier for copy from file storage to blob storage. As a workaround, I use the following code snippet and NuGet packages to copy directly from file share to blob storage.

1. Azure.Storage.Files.Shares
2. Azure.Storage.Blobs

   ```
   ShareFileClient shareFileClient = GetFile(); // get the ShareFileClient

   var blobClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobConnectionString);
   var container = blobClient.GetBlobContainerClient(blobContainerName);
   var destBlob = container.GetBlobClient(shareFile.Path); // set the path of the destination blob
   await destBlob.StartCopyFromUriAsync(shareFile.Uri, accessTier: accessTier);
   ```

I got the idea from [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#copy-files), but the code was using the older version of FileShare SDK. My code uses the latest version.